# rails dates between 2 dates in specific format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date

I'm working with rails and what i need is to get all the dates between two specific dates, BUT **I need the dates in a specific format**. I've found several ways of generating an array of between dates but they are all in %Y/%d/%m and I need to be able to generate dates in a %d/%m/%Y format.

The code I've found so far:

```
(start_date..end_date).to_a.select

(start_date..end_date).map(&:to_s)
```

Adding strftime(%d/%m/%Y) on any of the other calls doesn't work. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do:

```
(start_date..end_date).map { |d| d.strftime("%d/%m/%Y") }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can take advantage of the I18n gem (The translation gem included now by default in Rails) and localize your dates. You can even define your own formats : see the [doc](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#adding-date-time-formats).

```
date_array.map do |some_date|
  I18n.l(some_date, format: '%d %B %Y')
end
```

Don't forget to include `nil` checks otherwise it'll crash.